# How to upload a Spark Dataframe to Azure Table Storage?

Tags: python, dataframe, azure, apache-spark, databricks

Is it possible to create a table in Azure Table Storage based on a Spark Dataframe using Python, any ideas?
I am working in Azure Databricks, and I have tried multiple alternatives to establish a connection with the table that I have created, I have a client_id and server_id, but I really would not know how to carry out this procedure correctly since nothing works.

Comment: Add details of your approach and error facing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Databricks does not natively support Azure Table Storage.

To use certain data services in Azure or Azure Databricks, you will need to set up various configurations. This includes connection settings, security credentials, and networking preferences.

In some cases, you might need administrative or power user privileges within your Azure account or Azure Databricks workspace. Additionally, for certain services, you may be required to create an Azure Databricks library and install it on a cluster.

The below are the data sources supported by Azure databricks:
[image]

To write to Table Storage from Databricks, You can use any one from the below:

- Python SDK
- Install Library
- Implement custom writer class
- Use REST API for Table Storage

**References:**

[Develop with Azure Cosmos DB for Table and Azure Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/support)

[Build an API for Table app with Python SDK and Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/quickstart-python?tabs=azure-portal)

[Table Storage REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-rest-api)

[What data services does Azure Databricks integrate with?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/#what-data-services-does-azure-databricks-integrate-with)